# How to get session level performance metrics as part of JMeter Listener/Report

Tags: jmeter

How to get number of successful and failure sessions, average response time and error percentage as part of JMeter Listener/Report. I am able to get the mentioned performance metrics for each request (for example HTTP Request) using Summary Report in JMeter but not session level metrics. We can get the session level metrics in WAPT tool

Comment: You can get session level metrics form Jmeter, but you've got to be more specific. What are your goals exactly? what do you have right now, and what would you like to track?

Comment: I have a JMeter test script to perform the following steps:
1. Login to my web based application
2. Change the address value in a text box and Save the details
3. Revert the address to original value
4. Save the details and logout of the application
I have totally 5 threads in my script and each thread has 4 users in it. So, when I perform the above steps for a single user in a thread, thats called a session. So, I need the following metrics for every session 
1. Number of successful sessions
2. Number of failure sessions
3. Average response time
4. Error percentage

Comment: @KirilS. I have provided you the details above. Could you please provide me a solutions or if you need further info. please let me know